# Vim static word wrap interactive 'smart' rebuilding

Tags: vim

Am a long time `kate` user switching to `vim`.

Wonder whether `vim` has an easily activable option (or for it has been coded a plugin) to 'smartly' apply static word wrap to large strings when coding major languages: C/C++, Java, Python, PHP, (more follow).

Not only while writing but also while applying an indentation modification to a visual text block, or (un)?commenting it. Let us have a pseudo-Java situation like:

```
  1         String loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipi" +
  2                         "sicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut " +
  3                         "labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim v" +
  4                         "eniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris " +
  5                         "nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aut" +
  6                         "e irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit" +
  7                         " esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Exc" +
  8                         "epteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt" +
  9                         " in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est" +
 10                         " laborum.";
  ~
```

At some point would want to add or remove some indentation levels, but relying in the editor to rebuild the whole language provisioned string with our static word wrap rules. Suppose now by some reason it is desirable to remove two spaces of indentation, the desired output would be:

```
  1       String loremIpsum = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisi" +
  2                       "cing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labo" +
  3                       "re et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam," +
  4                       " quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut " +
  5                       "aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure do" +
  6                       "lor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum" +
  7                       " dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint oc" +
  8                       "caeact cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui of" +
  9                       "ficia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.";
  ~
```

Which is the tool for this to be constructed by `vim`?

Comment: Could you also post what you want to obtain?

Comment: Done an edit about it.

Answer (score 1):

With Vim, the `gq` command reformats lines; this can even be done as-you-type with `:set formatoptions+=a`.

Unfortunately, Vim's built-in capabilities are limited to basic stuff (see `:help fo-table`); elaborate and language-specific formatters are meant to be provided by external programs (`'formatprg'`), or Vimscript (`'formatexpr'`), the latter one I haven't actually seen used yet.

So, if you're lucky you'll find an external code formatter program that can be integrated, or you'll have to write such a thing yourself.

Comment: As a 'más difícil todavía', when at some point (in the near future) this works for me, do you think that would be easy to put it to work also in [vrapper](http://vrapper.sourceforge.net/home/)?

Comment: "Vrapper imitates the behaviour of Vim while still using whatever editor you have opened in the workbench". As it's not Vim, this would require the tool to emulate the `'formatprg'` option, which is not likely. I don't like vi-emulations like this, because although they provide mostly complete support for the original Vi(m) commands, they miss out on the great extension capabilities of Vim.

Comment: Maybe writing a `vim` plugin that would take advange of the `fmt` command for doing this things is what is needed here? Further there are some languages that can smartly concatenate strings without plus signs in between (IINM PHP or Scala), while many others not (C, C++, Python, Java...) and the plugin should behave accordingly when formatting each language. May not be calling an external command too much performance centric, but that could be a starting point.

Comment: In fact the C language would require not adding a plus sign, but wrapping the entire substring inside its very printf(...) call. As a possibility

Comment: printf(...), strcpy(...), strcat(...)... whatever applies, but this would be working really tight coupled with each task. But I definitely would (not too much seriously) consider applying that to long strcat strings, if I would be so crazy to not be using a modern way of string processing.